# App won't recognize gestures, like pan, using Hammer.JS in Angular 11

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I can't recognize any gestures, such as swipe, pan, in my Angular app using Hammer.JS. It's set up like this:

**package.json:**

```
"@angular/core": "11.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ HammerModule, BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts:**

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
onPan(evt) {
    console.log("onPAN");
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="gesture__zone" (pan)="onPan($event)">
  <h1>Pan Gesture</h1>
</div>
```

*I tested 'mousedown', it works well. Just any gestures in hammerJs won't work.*

Is there something wrong with my config? Can anyone please help me to find the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get this work on Angular 11 only by installing hammerjs manually with:

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule, HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [....],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [{
    ...
    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
    useClass: HammerConfig
  }]
```

I know this should work without

Answer (score 10):

you should **imports HammerModule after BrowserModule** like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HammerModule, 
   FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I don't know why everywhere that's written how to configure gesture - missing this step!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/hammerjs it seem like that hammerJS is not active any more

Comment: It won't work on my side. I used " npm install --save @egjs/hammerjs" to install this package, remove all hammerjs. Then on app.module.ts, I added this: import HammerModule from "@egjs/hammerjs"; @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ HammerModule ]
})

Answer (score 0):

For those for whom [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870979/9570942) answer didn't work, try to also add `import 'hammerjs';` to whether main.ts or polyfills.ts